# Adding HTML markup in react bootstrap tooltip

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is it possible to show some custom HTML markup in react bootstrap tooltip component

```
<OverlayTrigger
          placement='top'
          trigger={['click', 'hover', 'focus']}
          overlay={
            <Tooltip id='Description__tooltip'>
              {record.desc}
            </Tooltip>
          }
        >
          <i className='fa fa-info-circle fa-sm' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </OverlayTrigger>
```

The value displayed in the tooltip (record.desc) is having some html code which I want to add to this tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

```
<Tooltip id='Description__tooltip'>
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: record.desc}} />
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: It works.. Although will have to find something to prevent XSS :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with ***dangerouslySetInnerHTML***

```
const tooltip = (
  <Tooltip id="Description__tooltip">
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: record.desc}} />
  </Tooltip>
);

 <OverlayTrigger
     placement='top'
     trigger={['click', 'hover', 'focus']}
     overlay={tooltip}
 >
     <i className='fa fa-info-circle fa-sm' aria-hidden='true'></i>
 </OverlayTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

from in your problem, if you want to insert DOM Element in children, we must do function to wrapper the props which DOM element contains. we can use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**. example code like this below.

```
<OverlayTrigger
      placement='top'
        trigger={['click', 'hover', 'focus']}
        overlay={
         <Tooltip id='Description__tooltip'>
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:record.desc}} />
         </Tooltip>
        }
     >
     <i className='fa fa-info-circle fa-sm' aria-hidden='true'></i>
</OverlayTrigger>
```